# ¿contador no empieza al primer recorrido?

Tags: java

tengo un FormulariosVendidosTotal=0; luego mando el numero a un txtfied, después actualiza el numero en una bd.
Todo esto se realiza, entonces cual es el problema, el problema es que digamos que el contador este en cero, con presionar el botón una ves el contador queda en uno y en la base de datos no se actualiza, ahora vuelvo a presionar el botón, el contador queda en 2 y la base de datos ahora queda en 1. ahora vuelvo a presionar el botón, el contador queda en 3 y la base de datos en 2 y así sucesivamente.

el contador es InscritosTotal

no se si sea orden del código o algo, me disculpo soy nuevo en esto.

```
FormulariosVendidosTotal=0;

    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
     personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    
     
    
    if (rbInscrito.isSelected()) {
        InscritosTotal++;
        InscritosDia++;
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
        FormulariosVendidosDia++;
        
        String u =rbInscrito.getActionCommand();
        txtInscrito.setText(u);
        
        //MANDA EL NUMERO DEL CONTADOR A UN TXT 
        txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(FormulariosVendidosTotal));
```

//ACTUALIZA EL NUMERO EN LA BD, RECOGIENDO EL NUMERO DEL TXT QUE TIENE EL CONTADOR

```
     String strSentenciaInser = String.format("UPDATE contador SET formVendiTotal='%s'",oPersonas.getFormVTotal());
     objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInser); 
    }
```

> // TRAE DATO DE LA BD Y LOS COLOCA EN UN TEXTFIELD

```
  conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    try {
     ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM contador");
     while (resultado.next()) {
     int counterID = resultado.getInt("formVendiTotal");System.out.println(counterID);
      txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(counterID));
      FormulariosVendidosTotal=FormulariosVendidosTotal+counterID;
      
      
    };
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿De qué contador hablas exactamente (nombre de la variable)? Luego, parecería que escribes un código demasiado repetitivo, lo digo al ver variables con nombre como `cadena1, cadena2, cadena99999` ... hay mejores formas de organizar, quizá conviene repensar su diseño en general, tanto a nivel de código como de base de datos.

Comment: ya lo arregle un poco

Comment: Hay un condicional, para que el valor se incremente: `if (rbInscrito.isSelected()) {` ¿verificaste que ese condicional se cumple? Cuando ese condicional no se cumpla, el contador no se incrementará.

Comment: si se cumple, osea doy un click y el contador incrementa a 1, pero en la bd sigue en cero, vuelvo a dar el clik el contador incrementa de nuevo quedaria en dos y en la bd  se actualiza a 1 y asi sucesivamente, el contador iria en 3 y la bd en 2, es como si no cogiera el primer click que le diera

Comment: Pero, no veo que uses `InscritosTotal` en tu sentencia `UPDATE`

Comment: ya lo edite, ahora si ese es el código, y no encuentro el problema

Comment: Me refiero a esto: `String strSentenciaInser = String.format("UPDATE contador SET formVendiTotal='%s'",oPersonas.getFormVTotal());` se supone que esa es la sentencia que se ejecuta, pero, en esa sentencia tú no usas a `InscritosTotal`.

Comment: Ni tampoco estás asignando a `txtFormVTotal` el valor de `InscritosTotal` ... asumiendo que quisieras tomar de un textfield el nuevo valor.... Todo esto es tratando de adivinar el asunto, el cual no es aún del todo claro.

Comment: ya coloque el codigo que utilizo al inicar el programa para que me traiga el numero que esta en la bd al txtFormVTotal

Comment: Sin el contexto es complicado ver dónde falla el código. Te aconsejo que pongas puntos de interrupción y vayas verificando los valores de cada dato implicado para ver dónde está el problema.